# Java Apache POI - word document opens itself after creation

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm using Java with Apache POI to create a word document based on an ArrayList. Everything works, except that I want that the specific Word document opens itself after it is created. Does anyone know a method or simply how I can achieve this

```
try{
        FileOutputStream outStream = new 
        FileOutputStream("CarteBoissons.docx");
        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();
        XWPFParagraph paraTit = doc.createParagraph();
        XWPFRun paraTitRun = paraTit.createRun();
        paraTitRun.setBold(true);
        paraTitRun.setFontSize(20);
        paraTitRun.setText("CARTE BOISSONS" +
                "" +
                "" +
                "");
 doc.write(outStream);
        outStream.close();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Le document Word a été créé");
    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
```

Comment: Share your code which you tried so far.

Comment: `Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("path to word"));` this or you replace `new File("path to word")` with the file object that represents yourword file

Comment: Thanks, It opens itself up now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you wanted something like this

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("path to your word file"));
```

Use this in your code when you want to open the file with your default application

Comment: I added the code and it opened the document were the word doc is saved, thanks!

Comment: I am glad it works. Consider to upvote or mark as answer.

Comment: I can't upvote because I'm new to this site, but it is marked.